# Configurable items Default price issue on Magento2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, price

For configurable products by default the lowest price of the associated products is displaying.
But i want to display highest price of the associated products.

How to fix this issue on Magento2 . Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot edit the configurable product price one the configurable product is created. And there were no any option/setting to display highest price of its associated products.

[image]

Comment: We are using Magento ver. 2.0.1. There is no field to add the price for Configurable products.

Comment: I think there were no any major changes in configurable product functionality in different ver.

Comment: Now i created the Configurable product and assigned associated products. In frontend for configurable product showing with lowest price before selecting options, but i want to display highest price.